# Вставка и выполнение полученного кода

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension, request, callback, sendmessage

Посылаю запросы из `content.js` в `background.js`. Обратно получаю строки кода (в некоторых случаях большого объема) и хочу сразу их выполнить.

**content.js**

```
chrome.extension.sendMessage({"param1": true, "param2": "qwerty"}, function(backMessage){
    backMessage;
});
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, f_callback){
    if(request.param1 == true){
        f_callback('alert("Welcome")');
    else
        f_callback('break');    // Дальнейший код в content.js НЕ должен выполняться
});
```

***Возможно ли это осуществить ??? И как правильно ???***

Comment: что это за строки и для чего это делается?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выполнить код полученный в виде строки возможно.

Вариант 1.

Использовать функцию `eval`. Она выполняет код представленный в виде строки.
Строка в свою очередь может содержать операторы `javascript`.

```
eval("alert('Stackoverflow')");
```

Использовать функцию нужно осторожно, так как имеет место вероятность выполнения вредоносного кода.

Не знаю где применение данной функции было бы оправдано.

Вариант 2.

Использовать функцию `chrome.tabs.executeScript`. Она вставляет переданный ей код на страницу.

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {
            code: 'document.body.style.transform = "scaleX(1)";'
        }, function(result) { // Something}
```

В данном примере передаем функции:

- идентификатор вкладки в которую должен быть вставлен код. Необязательный.
- объект описывающий код, который должен быть вставлен. В примере передается только свойство `code` содержащее код в виде строки. Можно
  указывать имя скрипта, но вместо свойства `code` должно быть `file`. Имеет и другие свойства.
- функция обратного вызова, которая сработает после того, как будет вставлен код на страницу. Необязательный.

Вариант 3.

Вместо того, чтобы передавать строки кода, передавать сообщения, которые сигнализируют о том что нужно сделать. После получения сообщения выполяется какой-нибудь метод.

Например получили сообщение из `background`, проверяем хранилище где хранятся действия с ассоциированным ими сообщениями.

`{"getItem": false}`. Проверяем хранилище и ищем метод который ассоциирован с сообщением `getItem`. Если находим - вызываем его и передаем ему данные.

На одно сообщение можно навесить несколько действий.

Думаю этот вариант лучше всего подходит.

Можно не писать своего функционала хранения действий и т.п, а использовать объект `window`:

```
window["getItem"](param);
```

Но тут уже несколько действий дернуть не получится.

[eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) | [executeScript](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript)